# Show One Div and Hide Another Div when Click on button

Tags: javascript, css

What I want to do is, when I click on button then one div should disappear and another should appear and if i click on the same button one more time, then first one should appear and second one should disappear. This would go until I click on the button.

What I tried:

**JavaScript:**

```
function change_image(){
    var flag = true;
    if(flag){
        document.getElementById('speaker_main_div_with_rounded_image').style.display="none";
        document.getElementById('speaker_main_div_with_square_image').style.display="block";
        flag = false;
    } else {
        document.getElementById('speaker_main_div_with_rounded_image').style.display="block";
        document.getElementById('speaker_main_div_with_square_image').style.display="none";
        flag = true;
    }
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<input type="button" value="Click Here to get another image" onClick="change_image(this)">
```

Any help would be grateful.

Thank You.

Comment: Where is your html? what exactly is the problem?

Comment: `<input type="button" value="Click Here to get another image" onClick="change_image(this)">`

Comment: when i click on the button for the first time then first div gets disappear and second div gets appear but when i click on the button once again that is second time then it is not showing first div and disappearing second div.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `flag` variable is local, and its value is always the same when function is called. Initialize it with:

```
var flag = document.getElementById('speaker_main_div_with_rounded_image').style.display !== 'none';
```

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution using jQuery Library .

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
       <head>
          <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
          <script>
             $(document).ready(function(){
              $("#btn1").click(function(){
               $("#div1").toggle();
               $("#div2").toggle();
              });
             });
          </script>
          <style>
             .hide{
             display:none;
             }
          </style>
       </head>
       <body>
          <button type="button" id="btn1">Toggle</button>
          <div id ="div1">
             I am div 1
          </div>
          <div id ="div2" class="hide">
             I am div 2
          </div>
       </body>
    </html>
```